# Difference between $R[x]$ and $R[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, formal-power-series

I am watching Richard E. BORCHERDS
lectures on Rings and Modules [21 Formal power series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8nfI6ROBuQ&list=PL8yHsr3EFj52XDLrmvrFDgwcf6XOm2TEE&index=21) and have a question about relationship between $R[x]$ and $R[[x]]$.

Richard just say $R[[x]]$ as formal power series and state $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2+ \cdots, a_i \in R$, and denote $R[[x]] = \lim_{\leftarrow} R[x]/(x^m)$ inverse limit of $R[x]/(x^m)$. [Can you explain this in more detail? I watch them over and over again but can not understand its meaning.]

But I am confused (maybe because I am not familiar with inverse limits). I know $R[x]$ is a polynomial ring $R[x]= \{ a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n | a_i \in R\}$, What is the relation between them? My naive guess is $R[[x]]$ is infinite sums, but $R[x]$ is finite sums. What makes them different in many aspects?

I know $R$ is UFD then $R[x]$ is UFD but $R[[x]]$ is not UFD.
And $R$ is Noetherian then $R[x]$ is Noetherian but $R[[x]]$ is also Noetherian
i.e., all the ideals are finitely generated.

So what makes $R[x]$ and $R[[x]]$ similar and different approaching some mathematical properties?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not specific enough to answer. These are different rings with different properties. You have listed some. They have different purposes. There's nothing much more to say at the level of generality you ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverse limit of the rings $E_m=R[x]/(x^m)$ just means that if $m>n$ then there is a natural map $E_m\to E_n$ and that we consider the set of sequences $(a_m)_{m\ge 1}$ with $ a_m\in E_m$ and such that $m>n\implies a_m = a_n\bmod (x^n)$. This set is naturally a ring: $(a_m)+(b_m)= (a_m+b_m)$, $(a_m)(b_m)=(a_mb_m)$ (addition and multiplication in each ring $E_m$) and it is naturally isomorphic to the ring of formal power series. For a power series $\sum_{k\ge 0} c_k x^k$, letting $a_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_k x^k$ then $(a_m)$ is an element of $\varprojlim R[x]/(x^m)$ and they are all of this form.

Answer (score 2):

$R[X]$ is the polynomial ring as you know it. $R[[X]]$ is the ring of formal power series, we define
$$ R[[X]] = \varprojlim_n R[X]/(X)^n.$$
Elements in this ring are sequences $(f_n+(X)^n)_n$ of residue classes of polynomials $f_n \in R[X]$ with the property that if $m\ge n$ then $f_m + (X)^n = f_n + (X)^n$ and so it is regarded as a subring of $\prod_n R[X]/(X)^n$.
What is the intuition here? Well, a power series can be thought of as a sequence of polynomials of finite degree increasing degree where we chop off the series at a given point. But we cant take any arbitrary sequence, the condition we want for this sequence to represent a power series is that the terms must "agree" i.e. if I look take the series up to its $m$-th term and chop it down to its $n$-th term where $m\ge n$ then I should get the sequences $n$-th term. But this is *precisely* the condition specified in the definition.